# How to get dimensions and load PDF Page?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, pdfkit, cgrect

I have a single PDF page in Swift Xcode iOS,

```
let page = self.pdfDocument!.page(at: page_index!)!
```

and I wish to get the dimensions of the page. When I create a breakpoint on the code above, I can see just the PDF. How can I get the width and height of my PDF page and its relative location on my screen (x, y) from top left?

In addition, I wish to load this single page (not the entire pdfDocument) into QuickLookPreviewContainer. How can I get a NSURL of this page with the code above?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what type of object is `pdfDocument` ?

Comment: @LewWinczynski It's a PDF document. I imported PDFKit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get a page dimension for `PDFPage` doing the following:

```
let page = self.pdfDocument!.page(at: page_index!)!
let bounds = page?.bounds(for: PDFDisplayBox.mediaBox)
let size = bounds?.size
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Given this certain page, is it possible to load just that page into the QuickView Controller?